# Mysql alias the chain of inner joins issue

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

I have the following query

```
select *
from
    reservation r,
    (
        assignment a
        INNER JOIN class_ c ON a.class_id = c.uniqueid
        INNER JOIN scheduling_subpart ss ON c.subpart_id = ss.uniqueid
        INNER JOIN instr_offering_config ioc ON ss.config_id = ioc.uniqueid
    ) as io
where
    io.solution_id in (32931842) and
    io = r.offering_id
```

Note: solution_id is column on the assignment table.

I want the who inner joins in parenthesis to be aliased with io but I'm getting a syntax error:

> Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as io where io.solution_id in (32931842) and io = r.offering_id'

Comment: As Gordon Linoff is oft to say, _always_ use explicit join syntax.  From what I see, you are doing a cross join between the `reservation` and `assignment` tables, and I doubt you want to be doing this.

Comment: written as hibernate query looks like this:
select distinct r.group from StudentGroupReservation r, Assignment a inner join a.clazz.schedulingSubpart.instrOfferingConfig as io where "+
           "a.solution.uniqueId in ("+solutionIdsStr+") and io = r.instructionalOffering");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you mean to do this:

```
select *
from
reservation r,
(
    select * from assignment a ///  You missed the  select * from 
    INNER JOIN class_ c ON a.class_id = c.uniqueid
    INNER JOIN scheduling_subpart ss ON c.subpart_id = ss.uniqueid
    INNER JOIN instr_offering_config ioc ON ss.config_id = ioc.uniqueid
) as io
where
io.solution_id in (32931842) and
io = r.offering_id
```